# Generate specific matrix in on line

Tags: matlab

I try to generate the following two matrix within one line (e.g. repmat, reshape) but I can not find a solution:

This is the first matrix

[image: First matrix]

And this is the second matrix:

[image: Second matrix]

Edit:
Homework would be fun...background:
I try to implement a simple image resize algorithm. Finally I want use the codegenerator to create the corresponding C code. This is the current implementation:

```
function [ J ] = resize( I, sc ) %#codegen

% Function implements an algorithm to scale down given image 'I' by factor 'sc':
%
% Input data description:
% I : Grayscale 2-dimensional image
% sc: Image scale factor [-]

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
assert( isa( I , 'uint8' ) );
assert( isa( sc, 'uint8' ) );
assert( ( sc >= 0 ) && ( sc <= 10 ) );

% Calculate scaled image size [pixel]:
ns = uint8( fix( size( I ) / single( sc ) ) );
nr = ns( 1 );
nc = ns( 2 );

% Number of elements within window:
nw = sc * sc;

% Resulting image:
J = zeros( ns, 'uint8' );

% Create index lookup table to access windows within 'I':
ri = reshape( 1 : sc * nr, sc, nr );
ci = reshape( 1 : sc * nc, sc, nc );

% Loop over image 'I' and calculate mean for each window 'w' of size [sc sc]:
% coder.unroll( );
for c = 1 : nc
%   coder.unroll( );
    for r = 1 : nr
        % Extract window 'I_w' of fixed size [sc sc] from image 'I': 
        I_w = I( ri( :, r ), ci( :, c ) );
            
        % Calculate mean of window 'I_w':
        s = uint16( 0 );
%       coder.unroll( );
        for i = 1 : nw
            s = s + uint16( I_w( i ) );
        end
        J( r, c ) = s / uint16( nw );                
    end
end
```

This works well. With I=[120 160], sc=6 I get:

```
  /* MATLAB Function: '<S4>/Resize' */
  for (loop_ub = 0; loop_ub < 26; loop_ub++) {
    for (r = 0; r < 20; r++) {
      s = 0U;
      for (nz = 0; nz < 36; nz++) {
        s = (uint16_T)((uint32_T)rtu_I[((ci[loop_ub * 6 + nz / 6] - 1) * 120 +
          ri[r * 6 + nz % 6]) - 1] + s);
      }

      z = (uint16_T)(s / 36U);
      s = (uint16_T)((uint32_T)s - (uint16_T)(z * 36U));
      if ((s > 0) && (s >= 18)) {
        z++;
      }

      rtb_I_sc[r + 20 * loop_ub] = (uint8_T)z;
    }
  }
```

Variables ci, ri are pre- computed by the codegenerator and const arrays within the C code. Nice. Calculating the image index has still a lot overhead:

```
 s = (uint16_T)((uint32_T)rtu_I[((ci[loop_ub * 6 + nz / 6] - 1) * 120 + ri[r * 6 + nz % 6]) - 1] + s);
```

Now my idea was to pre- compute all required indicies:

```
% Create index lookup table to access windows within 'I':
% ri = repelem( reshape( 1 : sc * nr, sc, [] ), sc, 1 );
% ri = repmat( ri, 1, nr );
% 
% ci = repelem( reshape( 1 : sc * nc, sc, [] ), 1, nc );
% ci = repmat( ci, sc, 1 );
% 
% id = sub2ind( size( I ), ri(:), ci(:) );
% 
% id = reshape( id, N, [] );
% 
% % Loop over image 'I' and calculate mean for each window 'w' of size [sc sc]:
% for c = 1 : nc
%     for r = 1 : nr
%         % Extract window 'I_w' of fixed size [sc sc] from image 'I': 
%         I_w = I( id( :, r * c ) );
%             
%         % Calculate mean of window 'I_w':
%         s = uint16( 0 );
%         for i = 1 : N
%             s = s + uint16( I_w( i ) );
%         end
%         J( r, c ) = s / uint16( N );                
%     end
% end
```

Above code is not working properly at all, but the main issue is that the indicies are not pre-computed. The implementation seems to be too complicate for the code generator. Therefore I was looking for some magic reshape (whatever) commands to setup the lookup tables.

Comment: Why one line? Sounds like a ridiculous requirement. Anyway, have you been able to generate these matrices at all? Please show us how far you’ve gotten. We don’t want to be doing your homework for you.

Comment: Hint: it can be done using addition with [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) and [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)

Comment: This can be more on-topic as a `tips` question in https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. But as Cris says, show your attempt

Comment: So now the question becomes, why are you not using `imresize`?